# How can I add brackets on the laravel eloquent? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My query is like this :

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE (seller_id = 1 OR buyer_id = 3) AND deleted_by NOT LIKE '%1%'
```

I want change it to laravel eloquent

I try like this :

```
Message::where('seller_id', auth()->user()->id)
       ->orWhere('buyer_id', auth()->user()->id)
       ->where('deleted_by', 'not like', '%'.auth()->user()->id.'%')
       ->get();
```

But, the result like this :

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE seller_id = 1 OR buyer_id = 3 AND deleted_by NOT LIKE '%1%'
```

Seems it need brackets

How can I add brackets on the laravel eloquent?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to put your where in a closure

```
Message::where(function($query){
    $query->where('buyer_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->orWhere('buyer_id', auth()->user()->id);
})
->where('deleted_by', 'not like', '%'.auth()->user()->id.'%')
->get();
```

Comment: I also add the object type "Builder"  before the  $query instance.
full Builder namespace is "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;"

Answer (score 7):

In such cases, use closure.

```
$userId = auth()->user()->id;
Message::where(function($q) use($userId){
    $q->where('buyer_id', $userId)
    ->orWhere('buyer_id', $userId);
})
->where('deleted_by', 'not like', '%'.$userId.'%')
->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Message::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('seller_id', auth()->user()->id)
      ->orWhere('buyer_id', auth()->user()->id);
})
->where('deleted_by', 'not like', '%'.auth()->user()->id.'%')
->get();
```

Try this, may be your problem get resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Message::where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('seller_id', auth()->user()->id)
                  ->orWhere('buyer_id', auth()->user()->id);
        })->where('deleted_by', 'not like', '%'.auth()->user()->id.'%')->get();
```